# Morelinq doesnt' work with .net framework 4.5.1

Tags: morelinq

I am using morelinq in my asp.net mvc framework 4.5.1 project and it it is not loading proper system.runtime dll.

```
 <package id="morelinq" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
    <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

it is throwing following error.

> The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

any clue? I do not want to use old version of morelinq.

Answer (score 0):

To implement the fix first expand out the existing web.config compilation section that looks like this (or similar) by default:

`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>`

Then add the following:

```
<assemblies>     
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
</assemblies>
```

So, you should have something looking like this in your `Web.Config` file (among other things I imagine):

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
  <assemblies>     
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```